# NLP: Why use two vectorizers (Bag of Words/TFIDF) in sklearn Pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, pipeline

I am trying to solve a text classification problem using `SVC` on `sklearn`. I also wanted to check which vectorizer would work best for my data: Bag of Words `CountVectorizer()` or TF-IDF `TfidfVectorizer()`

What I've been doing so far is using these two vectorizers separately, one after the other, then comparing their results.

```py
# Bag of Words (BoW)
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
features_train_cv = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(features_train)

# TF-IDF
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf_vec = TfidfVectorizer()
features_train_tfidf = tfidf_vec.fit_transform(features_train)

# Instantiate SVC
classifier_linear =  SVC(random_state=1, class_weight='balanced', kernel = "linear", C=1000)

# Fit SVC with BoW features
classifier_linear.fit(features_train_cv,target_train)
features_test_cv = count_vectorizer.transform(features_test)
target_test_pred_cv = classifier_linear.predict(features_test_cv)


# Confusion matrix: SVC with BoW features
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix(target_test, target_test_pred_cv))
[[ 689  517]
 [ 697 4890]]

# Fit SVC with TF-IDF features
classifier_linear.fit(features_train_tfidf,target_train)
features_test_tfidf = tfidf_vec.transform(features_test)
target_test_pred_tfidf = classifier_linear.predict(features_test_tfidf)

# Confusion matrix: SVC with TF-IDF features

[[ 701  505]
 [ 673 4914]]
```

I thought that maybe using `Pipeline` would make my code look more organized. But I noticed that in the suggested `Pipeline` code in [sklearn tutorial from the module official page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) includes two vectorizers: *both* `CountVectorizer()` (Bag of Words) *and* `TfidfVectorizer()`

```py
# from sklearn official tutorial
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
>>> text_clf = Pipeline([
...     ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
...     ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
...     ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
```

My impression was, you only need to do choose one vectorizer for your features. Wouldn't that mean that the data gets vectorized *twice*, once with simple term frequency then next with TF-IDF?

How would this code work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not two vectorizers. It's one vectorizer (CountVectorizer) followed by a transformer (TfidfTransformer). You could use one vectorizer (TfidfVectorizer) instead.

The [TfidfVectorizer docs](https://sklearn.org/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) note that TfidfVectorizer is:

> Equivalent to CountVectorizer followed by TfidfTransformer.

Comment: Crap, I didn't even notice! You can tell I'm new to this. Thanks